# CiviMail shows empty recipient list

Tags: civimail, groups

CiviCRM 4.7.24 on Drupal

Since updating to 4.7.24, no groups appear in the recipient list

[image]

Comment: Running into the same problem with CiviCRM 4.7.24 WordPress

Comment: Correction. Recipients are showing but, my client is unable to send out mailing lists. Getting a CRON not running error. When cron.php is run manually, there are no errors. Upgraded to PHP 7 after upgrade, but am seeing no Apache errors or CiviCRM error logs related to CiviMail

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this was a real problem. I cleared all Drupal caches and then it worked.